# python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip

I installed python 3.9.13 and it came with pip 22.0.4.
So I tried to upgrade pip for a latest version using 'pip install --upgrade pip' but an error occurred.

The message was like 'ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError. Consider using the --user option or check the permissions'

Then, I tried 'python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' instead and it was clear.

Is there any difference using 'python.exe -m' option?
I'd like to know what the difference is and what that command exactly means.
I searched for the option but couldn't find right answers.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: go to your terminal and type `python --help`  it will show you all of arguments and their meanings

Comment: All answered here: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I liked to know about!